# Block specific javascript statements from executing "globally" from a client side perspective

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

as you might see, this is my first post and a rather specific question I believe.

Here is the problem:
It is possible to block javascript as a whole or specific scripts as far as i could find out. What however if i globally want to stop the execution of specific javascript statements?

Practical example:
A website is utilising several javascripts many of which are useful and I would like to participate in their functionality with the permanent exclusion of any code that references overflow:hidden. I perceive that (CSS-Snippet?) to be malicious code by design. It can be easily circumvented and fixed through executing your own code. That's not what I'm talking about though.

Probable solutions:
- Remove the browsers capability of understanding that particular code
- Enforce overflow:auto
- Apply overflow:auto when the website is fully loaded automatically

The aforementioned solutions seem very unelegant to me and as you guys seem like a clever bunch maybe you can think of something less superfluous and practical.

All the goto addons I've tried only offer 1-off solutions or the need to repeat the task of counteracting those code snippets.

Current solution:

```
var r="html,body{overflow:auto !important;}";
var s=document.createElement("style");
s.type="text/css";
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r));
document.body.appendChild(s);
void 0;
```

Isn't there a way to tell FireFox (or chrome) to categorically ignore every single attempt to alter overflow:auto or similarly (perceived) malicious codes?

Comment: Why would you perceive `overflow:hidden` as malicious? *"to stop the execution of specific javascript statements"* - There isn't a specific JS statement that sets a CSS style, there are multiple ways to do that. There are browser add-ons that let you apply custom styles to all pages that you view, so you could try the `html,body{overflow:auto !important;}` with one of those.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is actually very useful in some situations, and not malicious at all. You should consider _where_ you actually don't want it to be and set a specific CSS rule that sets `overflow: auto !important`.

Comment: Thank you "nnnnnn" and Luca De Nardi, for your input.
nnnnnn I perceive it as malicious because of the following:
The only times I've seen it used was to stop the User from scrolling on a Website that needed scrolling to function properly and force the user (through nuisances) to react to a pop-in. 

LucaDeNardi Since I know that I want it nowhere (because I don't consider restricting features in this instance useful). Thank you for your input anyways

Comment: @NielsPeter The useful situations I was talking about are, for example, some containers that want to "cut" text or shapes to achieve some cool effects. Just note that removing all the hidden overflows will make these sites look awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to set a property for all the elements in the website you could try this jQuery code

```
$('*').attr('style', ($('*').attr('style') || '') + ";color:black !important");
```

Here I get all the elements in the page and add my custom property in their style. In my case it was a black color, but you can have your overflow set to auto.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/s33trhv4/) and you'll see that I set many colors to the texts in the page, both with inline styles and through CSS and then the jQuery script forces all of them to be black.

The explanation is that an inline rule is more "powerful" than CSS rules, so if you set an inline rule to be important it is applied to the element instead of the CSS rule (as it overwrites it).

Comment: I forgot to say that the script has to be executed after the DOM loads, otherwise no element would match the selector.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. The code example in itself is useful, how would one go about applying that code to certain wildcard websites, or Browser tabs?

Comment: There are extensions for browser that allow you to execute Javascript or jQuery on websites, such as Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey